# @ControllerAdvice not working when @Around is present

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-aop

I am using Spring Boot 1.5.6 with AOP. For exception handling, I am using @ControllerAdvice with @ExceptionHandler and for logging of method entry/exit and invokation time I am using @Around of AOP. But when I call REST URL after intentionally throwing RuntimeException, the ExceptionHandler is not getting executed. If I replace @Around with @Before then it is working fine.Any suggestions...

UPDATE: I have re-thrown the Exception from @Around code block and now things a re working fine. But is it recommended?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@Around` aspect wraps around your entire method. If you don't throw your exception within that method, the exception will be consumed, and thus the exception handler won't kick in.

This means that you shouldn't catch any exception within your aspect. If you're trying to log the duration of a method, you should do it within the `finally` block:

```java
@Around("execution(* com.xyz.example.MyController.*(..))")
public void aroundCalls(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    logger.info("Before call");
    try {
        // This will throw "Throwable", so you'll have to add it to your method
        joinPoint.proceed(); 
    } finally {
        logger.info("After call");
    }
}
```